# Is it possible to get a slice of a slice in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I'm querying a mongo collection that has a field that is an array of arrays.  I want to find a record with a projection of one deep value out of the array of arrays.  Conceptually, this is a $slice of a $slice.  Is there a way to do this in Mongo?

For example - I have a record:

```
{
 name: "foo",
 text: [["part 1:1", "part 1:2"],["part 2:1","part 2:2"]] 
}
```

and want to select the record with projection "part 2:2".

```
db.collection.find({"name":"foo"},{text: {$slice: [1,1]}}
```

gives me the array with both "part 2:1" and "part 2:2".  How do I get just "part 2:2"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation pipeline to achieve a `$slice` chain, due to the limitations in the project statement being part of the find query.

The below query is invalid because the first `$slice` would return an array, instead of an index, and the execution of the outer scoped `$slice` fails.

```
db.collection.find({"name":"foo"},{text: {$slice:[{$slice: [1,1]}]}})
```

Moreover there is no way to work on an projected field in the same project statement, if possible, we could have modified the text further by applying a $slice to it.

The way to go would be:

- `Match` the record with the name as foo.
- `Unwind` the text array to get to the first level.
- `Unwind` again to get to the level that we want.
- `Group` the records together by name.
- `Project` the last record in the group which is also the last element
  of the last nested array.

The Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"name":"foo"}},
{$unwind:"$text"},
{$unwind:"$text"},
{$group:{"_id":"$name","text":{$last:"$text"}}},
{$project:{"name":"$_id","text":1}}
])
```

or if you would want to project an element appearing in a particular order, then you could use the `$skip` and `$limit` operations to achieve this.

```
var orderOfElement = 2;
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"name":"foo"}},
{$unwind:"$text"},
{$unwind:"$text"},
{$skip:orderOfElement -1},
{$limit:1}
])
```

Which projects the second element in order in the nested arrays.

Comment: Interesting!  Could we also do it with MapReduce?

Comment: Yes, but Map reduce are for more complex operations which are limited by the aggregation framework.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with multiple documents?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the specific part 2:2 the below query will help.

> db.user.find({"name":"foo"},{_id:0,name:0})[0].text[1][1];
>
> part 2:2